# Linq to NHibernate and Dynamic LINQ - query caching not working

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate, dynamic-linq

I have problem with the NHibernate's second level cache. When I use query:

```
        var items1 = Session.Query<Row>()
            .Cacheable();
            .Fetch(x => x.Field)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Field.Value)
            .ToList();
```

Everything is fine - the query is cached. But when I want to use Dynamic Linq ([a link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)):

```
       var items2 = Session.Query<Row>()
            .Cacheable();
            .Fetch(x => x.Field)
            .OrderBy("Field.Value")
            .ToList();
```

The query is not cached. Interesting thing is that, when I delete code line:

```
            .Fetch(x => x.Field)
```

caching works again. So the problem is with using Fetch and dynamic linq OrderBy methods together.

**EDIT:**

When I try do debug NH code (QueryKey class), debugger tells me that these two queries do not have the same ResultTransformer (and deeper: a listTransformation private instance).

Any ideas?

Chris

Comment: What version of NH do you use?

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with identifying the query by NH. I don't know how NH is storing query identifiers (whole SQL?) which are used to compare and load from cache. But when I compare ExpressionTree from first and second example (before calling ToList), they are the same.

Comment: Are the emitted query strings (sql) of both queries different? (I.e. including the Fetch?). NHibernate uses a `QueryKey` object for its query cache, which contains the query string, its parameters and filter values.

Comment: The emitted query strings are the same (checked by log4net).

Comment: When I try do debug NH code (QueryKey class), debugger tells me that these two queries do not have the same ResultTransformer (and deeper: a listTransformation instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I know what is the reason.

Dynamic Linq doesn't use Parameter Names in Linq Expressions. E.g. if I want to sort using lambda statemant, I write:

```
query.OrderBy(item => item.Name)
```

Above we see an `item` lambda parameter name.

When I use Dynamic linq:

```
query.OrderBy("Name")
```

in the result Queryable the lambda parameter in OrderBy mehod has no name (like `item` written above). We can illustrate the result like this:

```
query.OrderBy( => .Name)
```

And now, when NHibernate is decoding that Queryable expression and finds there an expression parameter that has no name, NH gives it a random name using GUID class. So every ordering using dynamic linq produces a Queryable Expression that has inconstant lambda parameter. This is the reason why NHibernate thinks that: `query.OrderBy("Name")` and `query.OrderBy("Name")` are not the same - they have another lamda parameters generated every time from scratch.

**SOLUTION**

If you want to fix it, you have to modify Dynamic Linq library.

1. In method `ExpressionParser.ProcessParameters` change line:

   ```
   if (parameters.Length == 1 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters[0].Name))
   ```

   to:

   ```
   if (parameters.Length == 1 && (parameters[0].Name == "it" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters[0].Name)))
   ```
2. In method `DynamicQueryable.OrderBy` change line:

   ```
   Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "")
   ```

   to:

   ```
   Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "it")
   ```

Now, `query.OrderBy("Name")` will produce `query.OrderBy(it => it.Name)`.

Cheers!

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this, the issue is fixed in NHibernate 3.3.2.